# Image background does not appear on pdf - TCPDF Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, tcpdf

I have a problem, I can't show the background image on the pdf, the output is only white blank pdf. I've checked the path to the background image and it's accessible. However, when you want to use it as a background, the image will not appear in the pdf.

I'm using laravel 8 with tcpdf ^^ Please help

```php
public function savePDF($id)
{
     $dokumen = Sertifikat::where('id',$id)->first();

     $path = Storage::url('dokumen/').$dokumen->image;
     

     PDF::SetTitle("Certificate");
     PDF::AddPage('L','A4');
     PDF::setImageScale(1);
     PDF::SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
     PDF::Image($path, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);


     $view = \View::make('sertifikat.view', ['sertifikat'=>$dokumen]);
     $html_content = $view->render();

     PDF::writeHTML($html_content, true, false, true, false, '');
     // D is the change of these two functions. Including D parameter will avoid
     // loading PDF in browser and allows downloading directly
     PDF::Output('Certificate.pdf');
}
```

**Controller**
https://pastebin.com/8RhNB5LF

**View**
https://pastebin.com/gPFMUGJi

**Error section on the website**
https://afgalaxy.com/sertifikat

Comment: send `sertifikat.view` file

Comment: '<html>
<body>
<div>
<table align="center" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="40%"><p style="color:black">Credentials : {{ $sertifikat->hash }}</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>'

Comment: have you tried to see content in `$html_content` by doing something like `return $html_content;` to see if html is rendered properly check the image dimensions of the background image & check if it can be rendered properly in A4 layout

Comment: What happens if you drop the `html` and `body` elements? The docs are a little unclear on this, but it's worth checking whether your `WriteHTML()` call might be _masking_ the background image you've set.

Comment: check whether any required php library/extension is missing or not. Like the php GD or someting.

Comment: I see that the background is also blank after return the $html content

Comment: Controller : https://pastebin.com/8RhNB5LF
View : https://pastebin.com/gPFMUGJi

Comment: then you need to change the view html to add the image in background, so that it appears in the rendered $html_content, [How to add background image](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_background.asp)